# SQL¿Cómo usar un case when con diferentes tablas?

Tags: sql, sybase

Tengo un caso en el que debo verificar si una condición se cumple, y si es así, pase a verificar otra condición que es de una tabla diferente a la primera condición... es decir:

```
        I_TIMPTRAS  =   case when convert(decimal(18,2), Fac_Iva) >= @Mon_Centa then
                            case Cre_Tipo   when @Tip_CreSim then
                                                case Cli_Tipo when @Tip_PerMor then @Str_Vacio
                                                                else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
                                                end
                                            else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
                            end
                        else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,6), @Mon_Cero)))
                        end,
```

Necesito meter dentro de la validación `case Cre_Tipo   when @Tip_CreSim then` otra validación la cual es:

```
case Cre_CobIVA when @Cob_NoIVA then @Str_Vacio else '123456789' end
```

Pero me marca un error, cabe mencionar que `Cli_Tipo` no es de la misma tabla donde se busca la `Cre_Tipo` , cómo podría agregar otro case dentro de la validación de `case Cre_Tipo   when @Tip_CreSim then`

Gracias!

Estoy usando ASE SYBASE

Así se ve como lo agregue:

```
        I_TIMPTRAS  = case when convert(decimal(18,2), Fac_Iva) >= @Mon_Centa then
                                case Cre_Tipo   when @Tip_CreSim then
                                                    case Cli_Tipo when @Tip_PerMor then @Str_Vacio
                                                                    else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
                                                    end
                                                    case Cre_CobIVA when @Cob_NoIVA then '1234567'
                                                                    else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
                                                    end
                                                else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
                                end
                               else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,6), @Mon_Cero)))
                        end,
```

Donde lo que agregue fue:

```
  case Cre_CobIVA when @Cob_NoIVA then '1234567'
        else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
    end
```

Y los errores que manda son de sintaxis cerca de la palabra 'case' y 'end'

Comment: Puedes compartir el motor de base de datos que estas utilizando y la version?

Comment: @Jbeltran  Estoy usando ASE SYBASE, gracias!

Comment: Procura incluir en tu pregunta el error completo que te sale al intentar la modificación

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo, agregue también como se ve con la línea que puse de código